# Minesweeper special case

Tags: algorithm, minesweeper

I need to make Minesweeper for an assignment but I can't find any info on this particular case.

[image]

0 is an empty space, numbers are numbers and * is mine. Considering the top 0 and the right 0 are not touching eachother, clicking any of the 0 should reveal the diagonally adjacent 0? I did not encounter this situation when playing the game online.

Comment: In "normal" Minesweeper, a 0 means that all 8 of its neighbors are safe to reveal, along with all the neighbors of any 0s that reveals, and so on... Unless you're doing a restricted version where only the cardinal directions count (no diagonals)... The bottom left of your example is not consistent, as well as several other elements.

Comment: I edited the question with a picture of a 9x9 randomly generated board with 10 mines. I can't figure it out (row 6-7 first 3-5 cols)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I select the spot in row 4, column 3 (1-based counting), that is a zero. This means that all 8 of the neighbors of that zero should be safe to reveal:

```
213
202
201
```

One of those neighbors (the one directly south of it, is also a zero, so its neighbors can be revealed, giving

```
213
202
201
210
```

Now the bottom right is also a zero. Revealing its neighbors gives

```
213
202
2011
2100
 100
```

That, in turn, reveals 3 additional zeros. The process continues until there are no more newly-revealed zeros to process, which should cover all the zeros in the bottom left quarter of the grid - any that can be reached from the original zero by a path passing through only zeroes, and using any of the 8 possible directions.

Comment: OK, so by pressing the row 4 col 3 the 0's from row 6 col 4 onwards should be revealed. It's what I was looking for, it just looked strage for some reason. Thx